# Python pandas: Select columns that their content does not contain a value

Tags: python, select, pandas

I would like to do the opposite of this :

```
data[data.ip.str.contains(':')]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `~` character like so:

`data[~data.ip.str.contains(':')]`